# Need to find a way to click on the message button using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
<button aria-label="Send message to Francesca Felder" class="message-anywhere-button mn-person-card__person-btn-ext button-secondary-medium link-without-visited-state" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1634="1634">
<span aria-hidden="true">Message</span>
<span class="visually-hidden">
    Send a message to Francesca Felder
</span>
```

Above is the button class I am trying to click using Selenium Webdriver.

I have tried doing this:

```
clickit = wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[span='Send a message to']")))
clickit.click()
```

It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Try to click on the css selector - by.css("message-anywhere-button mn-person-card__person-btn-ext button-secondary-medium.link-without-visited-state")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

`//button[span="Message"]` Thanks to Andersson

`//button//span[contains(text(), 'Send a message to')]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am getting this exception: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: try this `//span[contains(text(), 'Send a message to')]` , or can you post the full page source, it will help a lot

Comment: Still doesnt work and sure this is the source of the message button class, it's also in the question as well but here it is:                                       <button aria-label="Send message to Francesca Felder" class="message-anywhere-button mn-person-card__person-btn-ext button-secondary-medium link-without-visited-state" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1634="1634">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">Message</span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">
                Send a message to Francesca Felder
              </span>

Comment: paste the entire web page source, there might be multiple elements which the current selector is selecting, so complete source

Comment: please try this and see , `//button[contains(@aria-label, 'Send message to')]`

Comment: @Stack, The *syntax* itself is correct! OP could get required `button` with, for example `//button[span="Message"]`. Please update your answer with correct interpretation to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: missed that, changed now